# File system directory structure (SQL or NoSql)?

Tags: sql, filesystems, metadata, nosql

I want to make an app that will store in a database the file system directory structure of Linux. I don't know what kind of database is more suitable for this.
I will store also the metadata of the files.

Comment: Note that what you want to do is covered by several Oracle patents.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad, in my opinion, as it opens up a discussion whether one solution is better or another.

It's actually your call to make, but you can create a structure in Relational database for it. It's as simple as it gets.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  id_parent int REFERENCES mytable(id)
);
```

Postgres for example allows you to write recursive queries in which you would be able to build a path for every file in your file system. For more about `WITH` queries go [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html).